# What is a countable dense sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Recently I've found in a problem the term "countable dense sequence" in one interval and it really confused me. The point is: I know what a countable dense subset of an interval is - it is one countable subset of the interal, such that its closure is the whole interval.

In other words, any point on the interval is the limit of a sequence of points of the set, that in the particular case, happens to be countable.

Now, countable dense sequence is a term I never heard and I didn't find any definition whatsoever.

What it means to speak of "a countable dense sequence $\{r_n\}$ on the interal $[0,1]$"?

Comment: Essentially, sequence means countable set.

Answer (score 2):

What is meant is that the set
$$\{r_n,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
is countable and dense in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

As Olivier Moschetta points out is that $\{r_n,n \in \mathbb N\}$ is a likely answer. The term sequence might be used, since one possible characterization of a dense set $A  \subseteq X$ is that for all $x \in X$, there exists a sequence of $(a_n) \in A$ so that $(a_n) \to x$.

Since the set $A$ is countable, it makes sense to order the terms in a sequence $(a_n)$ and then say that it is dense if for all $x \in X$, there is a sub-sequence $(b_n)$ of $(a_n)$ so that $b_n \to x$.

In metric spaces, this is equivalent to saying that $\bar{A}=X$, or that $X$ is the closure of $A$.